# Pyspark Categorical data vectorization with numerical values associated with it

Tags: python, pyspark, vectorization

I'm a newbie in Pyspark programming. I need some help.

I have a dataset with a categorical feature and some associated numerical values with it. I would like to vectorize the categorical value including the associated numerical value with it. I have ~3 Million possible values for the categorical data column.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can group by UserID and aggregate the Quantity column into an array:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.groupBy('UserID').agg(F.collect_list('Quantity').alias('Quantity'))
```

But this may not ensure that the order of fruits remains correct. To achieve that, you can use a more sophisticated method that involves sorting:

```
df2 = df.groupBy('UserID').agg(
    F.expr("transform(array_sort(collect_list(array(`Fruit Purchased`, Quantity))), x -> x[1]) Quantity")
)
```

Or you can do a pivot instead, which also ensures order of fruits:

```
df2 = df.groupBy('UserID').pivot('Fruit Purchased').agg(F.first('Quantity'))
df3 = df2.select('UserID', F.array([c for c in df2.columns[1:]]).alias('Quantity'))
```

Comment: @SandipBirnale if the answer is helpful, consider marking it as accepted by clicking the tick button, thanks :)